# Can not access http://192.168.56.1:3000

Tags: vue.js, browser, nuxt.js, port

**Problem description**

I have a frontend application in Nuxt.js with Vue.js. I run the application in developer mode with
command `yarn dev`. Compiled successfully:

```
No issues found.
Waiting for file changes
Memory usage: 1.17 GB (RSS: 1.36 GB)
Listening on: http://192.168.56.1:3000/
```

I opened it in a browser and I got error:

```
This site cannot be reached. 
The server 192.168.56.1 took too long to respond.
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

**What I tried**

- I created new vue app and it worked fine on browser.
- I checked the ping:

```
>ping 192.168.56.1

Pinging 192.168.56.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.56.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

- I checked the port:

```
>netstat -ano | findstr :3000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11920
```

```
>npx kill-port 3000
Need to install the following packages:
  kill-port
Ok to proceed? (y) y
Process on port 3000 killed
```

After killed port I received `error Command failed with exit code 1.` So I restarted the application.

**Where is the problem? Why the application not working in the browser?**

Comment: Your Nuxt app looks quite big (`1.17 GB`), this may be a reason. What are you loading there? Try to remove some things and be sure that you're trying to load all of that on some decent hardware.

Comment: Do you have a Github link or a [repro]?

Comment: @kissu it is a very large ecommerce application with many files, that's why the large size. It's very large so it is not possible to share all code. But I can share some specific file, e.g. configuration file, if it helps.

Comment: I guess that some of them are not properly lazy-loaded/code-split'ed. At the end, sharing only relevant parts of the code is exactly what's expected. We will gladly appreciate some code, even tho the solution is probably to try to "remove" some parts, to at least debug the whole thing. Or try on a more powerful machine I guess.

Comment: @kissu So the problem is possibly in the application code? Or maybe is the app too big and won't load in this time?

Comment: Both can be possible. I mean, if you have a big app, there may be a LOT of things that may go wrong. Maybe try to `build` (or `generate`) it and preview it locally. First thing to check are usually the `package.json` and the `nuxt.config.js` files. Then looking at how things are wired overall.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by connecting to `http://localhost:3000`, instead of `http://192.168.56.1:3000`. Now it works.

Comment: Yeah, depends of your `host` settings too. Well played.